# Mysqli extension not activated after it was added to the php.ini file

Tags: php, mysqli

I have downloaded PHP 7 and connected it to Apache web server and it works fine, but I cannot activate the mysqli extension what I did was:
In the **php.ini file**, I removed the semicolon from **extension=php_mysqli.dll** , I have seen that the dll file exists in the folder C:\php\ext\ so I also added extension_dir = C:\php\ext .

However when I navigate to the phpinfo(); page on apache server , nothing has changed and there is no mysqli, only mysqlnd.
Any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: There is probably a `php.ini` in the `Apache\bin` folder. Thats what PHP when used under Apache will use

Comment: Have you restarted your Apache server? You'll need to do that after making configuration changes.

Comment: You can check the "Loaded Configuration File" value in the `phpinfo()` output to see which config file is being used.

Comment: @Don'tPanic it sais (none)

Comment: Okay. Do you have `PHPIniDir` set in your httpd.conf?

Answer (score 1):

The issue was resolved when I added **PHPIniDir "C:/php"** in the configuration file (httpd.conf) of Apache24