# Mysqli Extension Is Not Loading Despite Being Present In php.ini File With Other Configurations In Place

Tags: php, mysqli, configuration, php-8

I know the `dl()` function no longer works and I have tried to follow every directive I found but still I can't get the `mysqli` extension to work with my php.

In `phpinfo()`, the *"Loaded Configuration File"* is `"C:\MAMP\conf\php8.0.1\php.ini"`. I have opened this file and I have this on lines 543 and 544

```
; Directory in which the loadable extensions (modules) reside.
extension_dir = "C:\MAMP\bin\php\php8.0.1\ext\"
```

This also matches with what I have from `phpinfo()` under *"extension_dir"*.

I have also checked the specified folder and it contains a file named *"php_mysqli.dll"* among many other dll files.
Also, further down in the php.ini file mentioned above, I have this on lines 671 to 673:

```
extension=php_exif.dll
extension=php_mysqli.dll
extension=php_pdo_sqlite.dll
```

(The only exception is that in all of them, the word 'extension' is italicized; but that's the same thing with every other key in the file that is not commented out.)
I have also restarted my server and in fact my entire system, just to be sure, but still it's not being loaded. I check using `phpinfo()` and `extension_loaded('mysqli')`. I'm running php 8 on Windows 11.

I also checked out [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50358197/mysqli-extension-not-activated-after-it-was-added-to-the-php-ini-file) and I located `PHPIniDir` in my Apache24 configuration file (httpd.conf) but its value is `"C:\MAMP\conf\php8.0.1\php.ini"` which is the *"Loaded Configuration File"* my php uses. I'm not sure but I don't think I should edit that.

Since the mysqli extension is clearly not commented out, and everything else seems to be in place, why is it not being loaded? Is there something else I may be missing?

Edit: This was resolved when I changed the value of extension_dir in the php.ini file from `"C:\MAMP\bin\php\php8.0.1\ext\"` to `"C:\php\ext"`.
The extensions exist in both folders, so I just guessed that the former was where MAMP wanted it to read from while the latter is where it was initially supposed to read from. Plus that's also where I initially installed PHP before ever installing MAMP.
Anyways, not sure of the exact reason why it worked but it did.

Comment: What error message do you see? What does `extension_loaded('mysqli')` show? It could be that you didn't start your `mysql` server. Based on the path you provided I'm assuming you are using MAMP which I believe `Mysqli` comes bundled with

Comment: Instead of true, it was returning false, indicating that the extension was not yet loaded.

Yes, I was using MAMP. Didn't know it came with its own mysqli but I guess that makes sense as I was using MAMP's mysqli instead of PHP's mysqli. I don't really understand it but I'm glad it's working now.

Answer (score -2):

Changing the value of 'extension_dir' in the php.ini file to "C:\php\ext" solved my problem.